# Windows Server AppFabric 1.1 - Failed to read remote registry key from host

Tags: appfabric-cache, remote-registry

I have just installed and configured AppFabric cache cluster with one Host (the local machine). I use SQL as the Provider.

When I launch the Caching Administration Windows PowerShell using Administrator privileges,
I got the following error,

```
Use-CacheCluster : ErrorCode<ERRCAdmin040>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Failed to connect
to hosts in the cluster
At line:1 char:62
+ Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration;Use-CacheCluster <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Use-CacheCluster], DataCacheE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheExc
   eption,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.UseCacheClusterCommand
```

When I opened the DCacheAdministration.log it shows as below,

```
Host XXX is Reachable.,DistributedCache.CacheAdmin,Verbose,2013-5-2 13:54:06.042
Failed to read remote registry key from host XXX: Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCAdmin026>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Remote registry access failed on host XXX. Check if the required permissions are available and the host is not down. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AdminApi.RemoteRegistry64.OpenRemoteConnection(String hostName) at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AdminApi.RemoteRegistry64.OpenConnection(String hostName, String registryPath)at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AdminApi.CacheAdmin.GetRemoteRegistryKey(String hostName, Boolean writable)
               --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
               at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AdminApi.CacheAdmin.GetRemoteRegistryKey(String hostName, Boolean writable)
               at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AdminApi.CacheAdmin.GetServerVersion(String hostName),DistributedCache.CacheAdmin,Error,2013-5-2 13:54:08.053
```

Remote registry Service has been started. Which accounts needs read permission in regedit.exe? I have provided rights for LOCAL SERVICE (as Remote registry service use this as Logon) and for NETWORK SERVICE (Which i have used as Caching Service Account). Do i have to give any other permissions to make Registry key accessible??
Or what are the other things I need to check?

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue by enabling the Remote Registry Services and running it. I think AppFabric tries to connect to the remote server (which is local machine) using domain name to manipulate registry.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you see in the HOSTNAME reported in the error message "Failed to read remote registry key from host XXX". Is **XXX the machine name of the local machine or FQDN of the machine or is it pointing to a totally different machine ???**

If it is pointing to the local machine name or the FQDN of the local machine, then try putting an entry in the HOSTS file for the hostname pointing to 127.0.0.1 and see if that helps. If that doesn't then try restarting Remote Registry service and then run **Restart-CacheCluster** from the same PowerShell Caching Administration window and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is FQDN. I tried editing the host file also and alos restarted the service and cachecluster, but resulted in the same issue.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

    127.0.0.1   <My FQDN>
```